# Как сделать перенос строки в vue?

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите , как сделать так ,что если в переменной находится \n то оно его занимает на тег 
 и просто переносило предложение на следующую строчку ?

```js
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data() {
      return {
          activeTextRule: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, aperiam. Temporibus ab assumenda \n dolores doloribus consequuntur voluptatibus, quisquam suscipit veritatis repellat molestiae accusantium facilis sed voluptas, itaque fuga odio maxime'
      }
   },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">{{activeTextRule.split('\n').join('<br>') }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

и выкинуть ерунду из кода.